# I'm try to wrote in assembly

Tags: assembly

I try to write through the cell values ​​coup addresses 100h to 110h to negative values​​. (If the value is negative - it remains negative). Do not use the Compare CMP. so i try to check the MSB sign with text command and it isn't working I wrote this

```
code segment
assume ds:code,cs:code
start: mov ax,code
mov cx,10 
mov si,100h  
check:
mov al,[si]     
test al,10000000h//here i have problem!
je isntnegative
inc si
dec cx
cmp cx,0
jz finish
jmp check
isntnegative:
neg al
inc si
dec cx
cmp cx,0
jz finish
jmp check
finish:  
int 21h
nop
code ends
end start
```

I know it's long and effective but it's the best I can do at the moment.

Comment: It's very unclear what are you trying to do, what platform are you writing for, and what result are you expecting. Please edit, and provide some context.

Comment: like i say,i try to convert positive number to negative number

Comment: Why are you expecting to find anything sensible at address 100h? What platform are you targeting? On Windows or Linux, your program will most likely crash. On DOS, it'll process nonsense data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine `int 21h` indicates DOS. You need a subfunction number in `ah` to do any good. The last time you touched `ah` was the high byte of `code`! The `assume` directive does not make it so. You go as far as `mov ax, code`, you might as well `mov ds, ax` so what you told `assume` will actually be true.

You need to `test al, 80h` to see if it's negative. (You could also `or al, al`   or `and al, al` or `test al, al` to set the flags, and `js isnegative`... I guess you'd want to `jns isntnegative`)

If `al` isn't negative, you negate it. Do you then want to put the negated value back in your array? You don't do it. If you do, then it becomes important where your array at `100h` is! If you'd left `ds` where DOS leaves it in an .exe file, it would point to the PSP (Program Segment Prefix) and offset `100h` would probably be where your code starts. You probably don't want to scribble on it! By setting `ds` to `code`, offset `100h` will probably be past the code for this simple program. It might grow, though! You might want to put your array someplace safer. You might want to initialize it with known values. You might want to display it before and after to "prove it worked". Good start!

Answer (score 3):

AL is an 8-bit register; you appear to be expecting it to be 32 bits.  If you're working with 32-bit data, use the EAX register instead.  If you're working with 16-bit data, use AX.  And if you happen to be working with 64-bit data, use RAX.

And if you really are working with 8-bit values, then test against 10h, not 10000000h.

And assuming you're NOT working with 8-bit values, when you `inc si`, you probably need to increment it by 4 (for 32-bit values) or 2 (for 16-bit values).